# Error: ./src/index.js Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App')

Tags: node.js, mern

I keep on getting this error

```
./src/index.js Attempted import error: './App' does not contain a default export (imported as 'App').
```

This is my index.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals()
```

App.js code/ imports:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';
```

**How is this fixed? I tried all the other solutions but none worked out.**

Comment: Is that your full `App.js` code?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros those are just the imports, not the full script

Comment: What is exported from there?